# OO design of a game : moving player between rooms

Tags: java, oop

I'm quite new to OO design and I'm having a few issues designing a game:

The Game has a collection of Rooms.
Each room has a collection of Players and an Inventory.
Each Inventory has a collection of Items.

So currently, the Room has control of the Players. But with this design, I'm not sure if it would be possible to move a Player between Rooms which is what I want to do.

Then I thought of having a `Room currentRoom` in the Player class but I feel like I'd have issues with this as well. Also, a Player does not have a room so this doesn't seem very OO.

Any tips on how to design my game? Thanks!

Comment: You should have a Room class and create as many objects from the Room class as you need ie. number of rooms.  Then you should have Player objects create as many as you need.  Then within your Room Objects you should have some sort of list<Players> of players that are currently in that room...

Comment: This has been modelled before.  Here is an example of how a very old online game platform did it: http://www.hayseed.net/MOO/manuals/ProgrammersManual.html#SEC6

Comment: When a player moves from the room they are in to another room remove the player from the room they are in and add them to the new room.

Comment: Distinguish between player as the intelligent agent (Human, computer) and player as pawn on the board.

Comment: A player may not have a room, but he does have a location, and in this case, that location is a room, so `currentRoom` is not inappropriate to have. This would allow you to put players in a list at the board level, and then you can check the list to get current occupants of a room.

Answer (score 5):

+1: The "Collection with a current item" Software Design Pattern is very common.

---

You have several rooms in your game.

```
The `Game` has a collection of `Rooms`.
```

Then, the `Game` "manages" or "owns" the `Rooms`.

When an object "manages" or "owns" other objects, is in charge of allocation and deallocation ("creation" and "destruction" of objects in memory).

---

But:

```
Each `room` has a collection of `Players` and an `Inventory`.
```

Wait. You forgot that:

```
The `Game` has a collection of `Players`.
```

And:

```
Each `room` has a collection of `Players`.
```

Wait, the `Game`, also has the same collection of `Players`.

Careful with the "has" word.

In O.O.P., many objects can relate to other objects,
but, only one object can be the "manager of", (and "relate to", at the same time), another object.

Both, the `Room` (s) and the `Game`, have some relationship,
or association with the `Player` (s), but, only one object,
can be the "manager" of them.

Since, a `Player` is always part of the `Game`, but,
can leave a single, current, `Room`...

... then the room can reference the same collection of `Players`,
than the `Game`, but does not "manages" them.

---

Therefore, let's change the previous declarations into:

```
The `Game` manages a collection of `Players`.
Each `Room` relates to a collection of `Players`.
```

---

Now:

```
Each `room` has (a collection of | ) an `Inventory`.
```

Then, each `Room` "manages" or "owns" the `Inventory`.

Let's replace the `Inventory` word with `Items`:

```
Each `room` has a collection of `item`s, called an `Inventory`
```

---

So:

```
The `Game` manages a collection of `Rooms`.
The `Game` manages a collection of `Players`.
Each `Room` relates to a collection of `Players`.
Each `Player` relates to a single, current `Room`.
```

The problem is the "has" word. Means association, sometimes,
"manages" / "owns" objects, sometimes means "relates but does not manages" an object.

---

And, finally:

```
Each `Room` manages to a collection of `Items`, also called `Inventory`.
```

But, if a `Player` can take the `Items`, with  him / her,
and change `Room` (s), and each `Player`, may drop an `Item`,
into the `Room`, like dropping a gun, and, taking an axe.

Then things, can get a little confusing.

Lets say that an `item` "can be located in", instead of "has" by a `room`.

So, each `player` can relate to a collection of `Items`, and,
each `room` can relate to a collection of `Items`,
and, the `Items` are "managed" by the `Game`.

```
Each `Player` can relate to a collection of `Item` (s).
Each `Room` can relate to a collection of `Item` (s).
Each `Item`, maybe related to a `Room`,
can be located in a `Room`, but, not always.
Each `Item`, maybe related to a `Player`, but, not always.
Each `Item` is part of an universe called the `Game`.
So, the `Game` "manages" all the `Item` (s).
```

Cheers.